# Why is ZeroMQ message scrambled?

Tags: node.js, zeromq, amqp

I am using nodejs to call my tcp subscriber to read messages.

```
var zmq = require("zeromq"),
sock = zmq.socket("sub");
sock.connect("tcp://pubsub.besteffortc.com:7658");
sock.subscribe("/ASD/Travel");
console.log("Subscriber connected to port 3000");

sock.on("message", function(topic, message) {
  console.log(
    "received a message related to:",
    topic.toString(),
    "containing message:",
    message.toString()
  );
});
```

Output I am getting is the following. What might be the issue ?
- can it be that my IP address needs to be whitelisted to see actual data ?

Note: Topic and URL name is not the actual value its dummy values.
[image]

Comment: It could be an issue with character encoding. Are you using the same character encoding on both sides? How to do convert to the internal encoding that Node.js uses?

Comment: It looks like you need to decode this message, it appears to be binary. Check with the publisher in what format it delivers the message, you can't just receive from ZMQ and expect outputting the message will yield something human-readable.

Comment: it's GZIPped XML

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *What might be the issue ?*

There is one sure point in the ZeroMQ - **if** a message gets delivered at all ( for which a Zen-of-Zero does not pose any warranty ), **then** it is sure to be an exact bit-by-bit copy of the message, that the originator ( the `PUB` in the case here ) was intending to **`.send()`**

If you `.recv()` anything ( be it by the native API level `.recv()`-method or the wrapper provided `.on( "message", f(...){...} )`-handler ), be sure it carries the 1:1 bitmap of the payload provided by the originator ( unless your language wrapper did a dirty job of obfuscating your use of the documented ZeroMQ API, producing some nasty garbage ( which I would not bet on, yet it might be an issue - try any other ZeroMQ message-source, that is under your own control, to see if this happens or not ) )

> **Q** : *can it be that my IP address needs to be whitelisted to see actual data ?*

As explained in detail above, this item is not a ZeroMQ issue. If your app-level / ISO-OSI-above-5 behaviour depends on contracting some kind of abonnement, only after which you get "access-validation" ( be it by whitelisting or other kind ), then your problem stays in the business domain, not the programming one.

ZeroMQ has nothing to do with any of this. ZMQ/RFC-documentation is explicit on each ZeroMQ service-composition and leaves zero-space for random or undocumented behaviours.